# drools with multiple 'insertLogical' statement in then section and how to read those in java

Tags: java, drools

I have a set of rules from which I want to return two objects using two inserLogical keywords. Please help me thanks in advance.

```
rule "Issue Adult Bus Pass" when
  $p : Person( age >= 16 )
       IsAdult( person =$p )
  $p : Person( age <= 16 )
       IsNotAdult( person =$p )
then
    insertLogical(new AdultBusPass( "He is adult" ) );
    insertLogical(new AdultBusPass( "He is adult") );
end
```

above is just the sample Rule but I have a similar structure and want to return two `inserLogical` statements. Please let me know the best approach. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: @Esteban is it possible to read two insertLogical statements in then condition

Comment: I would recommend you to go over the documentation and/or a Drools book to understand how production rules work and how they are implemented in Drools. Rules don't "return" a value, and in Drools at least, you can write a condition with whatever class you have in your classpath. What you are trying to do, if I understand correctly, is possible. But if you don't take some time to learn more about Drools then you have a tough road above you.

Comment: @EstebanAliverti I want to insert to new Object into the facts when condition satisfies and want to read those facts and do some analysis.